# Local develop branch ahead of remote develop branch by 17 commits?

Tags: git, merge

I have two branches: `master` and `develop`. `develop` is ahead of `master` by many commits. Both branches are clean. A hotfix came up, so I created a new `hotfix` branch from master. I made the changes, did a checkout on master and then merged:

```
$ git merge hotfix
```

I didn't push. I did a checkout on develop and did the same merge. It seems to have worked, but when I do a `git status` on `develop`, I get the following message:

```
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/develop' by 17 commits.
```

I did a `git diff` and the only changes between the local and remote `develop` branches are the three files I edited with hotfix.

Why does Git think the remote branch is so behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you performed the checkout properly (`git checkout master` etc.), there's nothing you should really worry about.

The 17 commits are just those of the `hotfix` branch and the merge itself. It's not correct to measure the number of commits by the number of files or content that's been edited. It all depends on what you've added and what you've deleted. Going by your description at least, there's nothing suspicious you did. Your local `develop` branch is ahead of remote for a reason.

Comment: Merging `hotfix` into `develop` wasn't such a great idea, as it screwed up my development branch's history. All my "merged develop into master" commits now show up in my development branch for some reason. I tried reverting, but nothing worked. I'll just start over. Thanks!